# Frame to Video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to use ffmpeg to create a video from a set of sequences, where the number does not start from zero?

I used this code:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -pattern_type glob -i 'img-*.jpg' -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

but I get an error like:

> Could not open file : img-173.jpg

because there is a gap in the sequence.

Comment: Works for me. Show the complete log from the command.

Comment: This post also says that your command should work fine: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7300/how-to-get-ffmpeg-to-join-non-sequential-image-files-skip-by-3s/7320

Comment: Can run this and you post the output: `ffmpeg -version`. Old versions of FFmpeg don't support the globbing syntax you are using.

Comment: @curusarn The complete log from the command will show version info and more.

Comment: If this is on Windows, in my experience this syntax may not be available (i.e. you may simply need to write a script to properly rename the files sequentially, with proper leading 0's).